# React Native with Recoil unnecessary re-renders

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, recoiljs

I'm using Recoil along with keychain inside my app to determine userProfileState and userAuthState mostly to hold auth tokens, user profile info and userRoles.

So I have created those 2 atoms:

```
const userAuthState = atom<UserAuthState>({
  key: 'user.auth.state',
  default: {
    registrationState: null,
    role: '',
    token: '',
  },
  dangerouslyAllowMutability: false,
});

const userProfileState = atom<UserProfileState>({
  key: 'user.profile.state',
  default: {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    id: '',
    icon: '',
  },
});
export const authAtoms = { userAuthState, userProfileState }
```

Then I have custom hook useUserState where I handle keychain state and setting/reseting/updating atoms. I have tried to use selector instead of custom hook since keychain functions are async and I can't set them in selector set function (at least I didn't find way to do it).

I'm using userAuthState atom inside navigation to determine which navigator should render depends on userRole and registrationState that looks like this:

```
export const RootNavigator: React.FC = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RoutesStack>();
  const userAuthState = useRecoilValue(authAtoms.userAuthState);

  function isUserAuthenticated() {
    return (
      userAuthState?.registrationState === RegistrationState.Approved ||
      userAuthState?.registrationState === RegistrationState.Suspended
    );
  }

  <NavigationContainer onReady={() => hideSplashScreen()}>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        {isUserAuthenticated() ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="MainNavigator" component={MainNavigator} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="AuthNavigator" component={AuthNavigator} />
        )}
     </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
};
```

MainNavigator is bottom tab navigator, inside one of tabs is updateUserProfile where problem occurres. Problem is when user update profile info, lets say name then I'm using function from hook useUserState where I'm updating userProfileState atom and also updating keychain state (not updating userAuthState atom), userProfileState atom is updated but RootNavigator is re-rendered, this don't change screens but when I log something inside RootNavigator I can see that message is logged in console. As I know Recoil only re-render components that uses atoms whose state is changed. Why does updating state of userProfileInfo atom affects RootNavigator to re-render which uses userAuthState atom whose state isn't changed?

If I need to provide more information about this issue please comment which part.
Thanks!